# Find dependency/execution order of several statements

Tags: python, networkx

I have several statements like

```
# exhibit 1
a = 0
b = 0
c = d + a
d = a + b
```

which to be executed should be put in the right order

```
# exhibit 2
a = 0
b = 0
d = a + b # d before c
c = d + a
```

Is there a way to find the right execution order of the statement in exhibit 1?

I tried to used networkx with a directed graph and statement like

```
tree.add_edge(a, b)
tree.add_edge(b, d)
tree.add_edge(d, c)
tree.add_edge(a, c)
```

But I don't see how to traverse the tree so has to get exhibit 2.

I'm not restricted to networkx.
Any tool which do the job is fine for me.

My real target file has about 200 statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing you are looking for is called topological sorting http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting

There is also a simple python library called `toposort` https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toposort/1.0

Given a dictionary in the form of KEY depends on VALUES you run

```
from toposort import toposort_flatten 
toposort_flatten({2: {11}, 
                  9: {11, 8, 10},                    
                  10:{11, 3},     
                  11:{7, 5}, 
                  8: {7, 3}})
```

gives you a valid ordering

```
[3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 2, 10, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it with topological sorting. Python has have [a library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/toposort/1.0) for this.

```
In [3]: from toposort import toposort_flatten

In [4]: toposort_flatten({'d': {'a', 'b'}, 'c': {'a','b'}})
Out[4]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**Earlier answer:**

In bash we usually do this by `tsort` (stands for topological sort). Python must have a library for this.

```
$ tsort 
a d     
b d
a c
d c
a
b
d
c
```